# Tips to organize LaTeX presentations for a semester

Tags: teaching, presentation, latex

I am giving my first course this fall and, as a LaTeX enthusiast, plan to prepare my slides in LaTeX for all the usual reasons.

For those of you who also do this, I wonder what resources you use to manage your slides for a semester. For ex., do you have one "master presentation" with different "chapters" for different classes or some other strategy?

What's your best practice?

Comment: Relevant questions from TeX.SE include 1. [Output different beamer presentations from same tex file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52569/128923), 2. [Reusing slides from Beamer presentations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46711/128923), and 3. [Dynamically hide LaTeX beamer frame based on tags](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/167153/128923).

Comment: Off-topic, and not the fault of LaTeX, but every beamer presentation I have ever seen has been a long list of bullet points. I feel death by PowerPoint is even more likely for LaTeX presentations.

Comment: @henning That's because it's more difficult to write "free-form" content with Latex (e.g., playing around with columns and content position), so people feel more forced to write using those few constructs they know in Latex. (By the way, learning to use `block`s is a first way to reduce that effect and add a new structure to lay out content).

Comment: Not an answer, but in general you can manage TeX well with git. Start from there and prepare a master template.

Comment: If you are teaching for the first time and your material involves a lot of math I *strongly* suggest considering a blackboard (or whiteboard / similar) to deliver your material. It is incredibly hard to present pre-fabricated math on slides at a pace that is even remotely comparable to the time it takes the students to absorb the variables, concepts, and definitions. The time it takes to write down an equation is a useful speed limit! Go and ask your colleagues and their current students what they think works best for your kind of material. I'd be surprised if their consensus is beamer slides.

Comment: Having said that, the slides of course would be a great way to hand out the material to the students after (or before) the lecture. Although you could in that case probably forego the beamer/slide format and simple write up the lecture notes as a book.

Comment: As a fellow LaTeX enthusiast I strongly urge against using it to prepare illustration heavy documents unless you (a) know exactly what you're doing as *a graphic designer*, (b) sketch out every slide beforehand on paper. Slide presentation software fundamentally differs from text authoring software for a reason, and LaTeX fails to capture this distinction. Typical LaTeX slide decks clearly shows this deficiency.

Comment: Latex is amazing but isn't PowerPoint more practical at times?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni An alternative tool that allows for a more 'free-form' approach is Ipe. Primarily a tool for drawing precise figures, it can also create presentations (in the form of pdf slides, similar to beamer). LaTeX enthusiasts might prefer this over Powerpoint because 1. all textboxes can render LaTeX directly 2. While the editor is visible, it creates an human-readable xml file in the end. This means you can change everything exactly. Especially if you have a lot of figures in your presentation, Ipe can be very useful. The layer system also makes it easier to 'animate' those figures.

Comment: You might consider using MathJax/LaTeX-enabled Markdown slides. Markdown is much less of a hassle than Beamer and there are much better-looking templates available. It's also adapted to posting them online as HTML slides, which is preferable to PDFs for several reasons.

Answer (score 8):

I use a different file for each topic. Each file covers 1-2 hours of teaching, more or less.

All files are in the same per-course folder, and their names start with numbers which define the order of the topics, for instance `1-introduction.tex`, `2-polynomials.tex`, `2.5-rationalfunctions.tex`, `3-analytic.tex`... If I have to insert an extra topic at the last minute (or in the next year), I can do it by adding decimals like in the example with 2.5. :)

Dates are a bad idea because if you want to re-use the same material the next year you have to change all file names. :) Lecture numbers can also be quite fragile, so I prefer to use topics like this.

I just copy the same preamble over to each file, because I don't change the preamble too frequently. If I had to make more frequent changes to the preamble, probably I'd consider a custom Latex class, but for now it works for me like this so I keep it simple.

I suspect that this works well for me only because I have a good set of tools though: for instance, a file manager that uses natural sort order and an editor that can compile Latex without clobbering the directory with lots of `.aux` and `.log` files.

Another tip is: sometimes you notice weak points and mistakes only after giving a lecture. If there is a chance that you will be giving the same course next year, keep a file called `notes` where you note down all the things you'd like to change.

Comment: "Lecture numbers can also be quite fragile, so I prefer to use topics like this": well, also order numbers are fragile, otherwise you wouldn't have to add decimals for extra topics (reminds me of the time when in Basic you would number the program lines 10, 20, 30 etc. to leave space for extra lines....). Why then not just dropping numbers altogether and record the lecture order in another file?

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano Because I like to have my course sorted when I look at it in my file manager, so I don't have to look at an extra file. :) But I get your point, and I understand that this is just a hack, too.

Comment: Copying the preamble? Urgh. No doubt lots of people do that, but I have to say I'm surprised that somebody with 25.8k TeX.SE rep does it... to me, _not_ needing to copy anything ever is one of the main reasons for using sourcecode-based languages like LaTeX for document creation. It's not like you need to make an actual style file; simple `\include` of `.tex` sources would also do the trick.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I don't have 25.8k reputation on Tex.SE; I have 5.1k, and most of them come from questions. :)

Answer (score 4):

- Use \include and/or \input to insert repetitive latex code used in the slides. If you use chapters then you will still want to have a separate file for each chapter.
- Use git to do version control and backup your slides. This works well for changes through the years. If you put the slides into a public repository (github, bitbucket), your students/other teachers can help you fix typos.
- Subfolder graphics and other included files.
- Use a good latex editor that supports code folding and easy navigation of your documents. For example, eclipse (texlipse plugin) is organized into projects (with multiple files) and has a navigation/outline panel with the different sections/chapters/etc.. Even some commercial editors (overleaf) lack this feature! A good document/project navigation panel makes it almost irrelevant whether you use chapters or separate .tex files.
- \usepackage{beamer} is useful but not the only way to organize your slides. You may also simply write lecture notes and scroll through them while giving elaborations on the board.
- Make good use of packages like \usepackage{beameraudience} or \usepackage{versions} to distinguish between slides you use in class and the full lecture notes.

Answer (score 3):

My courses are usually a mixture of blackboard lectures and slide presentations, and along the years I taught more than 10 different courses, with slight changes in each course from year to year.

Given the above, my slides are divided in subfolders by course/topic/year because I need to track of the differences from one year to another.

Some courses have a few topics in common, but there are always differences that justify the creation of different slide decks targeted to each course.

Overall, if you don't have disk space limitations, this structure is quite flexible, but indeed, many folders will contain replicated material.

Answer (score 2):

So, I have small groups of slides (1,2, or 4 as necessary) about particular topics - then I can tailor a presentation level and content quite rapidly.

Comment: How’s does this look? Can you give a screenshot of what you mean?

Comment: Well, if I want to talk about solar panels, is it about orientation, or output calculation etc so I choose the slides I want and to the level I want. Examples of slides you can find anywhere...

Comment: Ahh so you organize by topic not eg date of presentation. How do you organize your slides though? Is it into eg folders by topic or?

Comment: Folders with the names of topics... Solar is a good one because then there is solar pv, solar orientation, solar thermal.. Solar orientation works for both pv and thermal...